# import JSONC files into react app and use the properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json-c

I have a app where i would like it to import all my jsonc files and be able to iterate through the objects i the files.

Right now i have this function, which imports the files:

```javascript
   function importAll(r) {
        let files = {};
        r.keys().map(item => { files[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item); });
        return files;
    }

    const files = (importAll(require.context('./Service-Requests/', true, /\.jsonc$/)));
```

It works, but when i then iterate over the objects i the jsonc files, i can not find the properties.

If i do a console.log the files i gives me this:
[image]

but if it is normal json files, i get the objects:
[image]

so how do I use the jsonc files so i can access the properties from each object??

i use this to loop through the files:

```javascript
Object.keys(files).forEach(key => {
            if (files[key].title === e.target.value) {
                setData(files[key])
                setInput(files[key].Input)
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you using a specific loader for JSON-C files?

Comment: no, not at the moment

Comment: That might be the issue then. There's a specific JSON-C loader here: https://github.com/rianma/jsonc-loader